# Swift JSON Decoding Nested Array

Tags: json, swift

I am struggling to decode this JSON I'm attempting to use. Here is an example of said JSON.

```
{
    "Thing1":1
    "Thing2":
    {
        "Thing21":2
        "Thing22":
        {
            "Thing221":3
        }        
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a fan of using QuickType (app.quicktype.io) to generate Codable code for JSON.

It outputs this (once you fix the missing commas in the initial JSON):

```
struct ParentElement: Codable {
    let thing1: Int
    let thing2: Thing2

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case thing1 = "Thing1"
        case thing2 = "Thing2"
    }
}

// MARK: - Thing2
struct Thing2: Codable {
    let thing21: Int
    let thing22: Thing22

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case thing21 = "Thing21"
        case thing22 = "Thing22"
    }
}

// MARK: - Thing22
struct Thing22: Codable {
    let thing221: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case thing221 = "Thing221"
    }
}
```

Then, you can parse like this:

```
func dealWithJSON(jsonData: Data) {
    do {
        let topLevel = try JSONDecoder().decode(ParentElement.self, from: jsonData)
        print(topLevel.thing2.thing21)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, you're amazing! I didn't know this resource existed. Apologies for the missing commas.